# Breakpoints not hit in VS2022 Version 17.4.1 blazor WASM app DotNet6

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, visual-studio-2022

I've been having issues with Blazor WASM (web assembly) not hitting any breakpoints in Visual Studio 2022. "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document" is the error message.  This happens on all my Blazor applications and even on a brand new solution with Blazor WASM as a new project. This happens on the stock application every time.

After trying every possible solution here and on MS's website, with no fix, I went ahead and uninstalled Visual Studio completely including all SDKs, rebooted the machine and re-installed VS2022 version 17.4.1.  I went to create a new solution and set a breakpoint on the Razor page (forecast) and it STILL won't hit the breakpoint.

This started about a week ago after a VS update was installed. I updated once more yesterday and the problem still persists. Since this affects all projects old and new (all DotNet6), I know the problem is a bug in VS2022 and it does not fix itself even after uninstall and reinstall.

I've scoured and tried every solution here and posted this problem to MS's site, but this could take weeks/months before they get to it (last bug I posted for DotNetFramework 4.8 was not acknowledged until a year later).

I've tried resetting VS to defaults, reinstalling Dotnet6 SDK, and dozens of other possible fixes, none of which work. All modules report "Skipped loading symbols", but I have no idea why!

Answer (score 1):

Ok. The complete reinstall did work, but I noticed VS set the browser to a non-compatible browser (for debugging), which was Firefox, so it didn't hit breakpoints until I changed the browser back to Edge (only Edge and Chrome allow breakpoints to be hit for Blazor WASM pages - good to know).
Anywho, it's hitting the breakpoints now! (just have to completely uninstall VS, all SDKs, all versions of DotNet(core) to version 7, then reinstall everything).  I wish there was a better answer, but VS for developing Blazor (and MAUI) is still buggy.